# Duplicate definition error

Tags: svn

```
[2017-07-28 10:36:17 - Bruce] res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\convert_icon_new_1.png.svntmp:0: error: Resource entry convert_icon_new_1 is already defined.
[2017-07-28 10:36:17 - Bruce] res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\convert_icon_new_1.png:0: Originally defined here.
```

but there`s no convert_icon_new_1.png.svntmp file in my project.

Comment: What is your question? How is it related to SVN?

Comment: I find it in the bin floder . i think it`s a temporary file. it`s a  problem when I fresh the svn.